# Preventing cursor change in Chrome when clicking on a link that calls history.pushState()

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, cursor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preventing cursor change on link click in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579215/preventing-cursor-change-on-link-click-in-chrome)

Clicking on a link in Chrome (not Safari or Firefox) that results in a call to history.pushState() changes the cursor from pointer to arrow. Can this behavior be prevented?

Example:

The only reason anyone would want the cursor to remain as a pointer after clicking on a link is if the link does not actually load another page but rather fires a JS event instead.

```
<a href="test">Test</a>

// JQuery
$("a").click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); }
```

With the above code, event.preventDefault (or returning false) will allow the cursor to remain a pointer after click. This will suffice for most uses, namely triggering a DOM manipulation and/or AJAX request.

The problem is with history.pushState():

```
// JQuery
$("a").click(function(event) {
    history.pushState(arg1, arg2, "/path");
    event.preventDefault(); return false;
}
```

Here the pointer DOES change to an arrow. Any ideas on how to stop that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried some CSS:

```
a {cursor: pointer;}
```

Comment: If not working, try a:visited and a:active

Comment: Last try: a{cursor: pointer !important;} or the same with visited and active like before

Comment: Yeah already tried using !important declarations. Thanks though.